# Difference between $(0, 1)$ and $[0 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I'm wondering if there's any real difference between $(0, 1)$ and $[0 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]$. Aren't they just the same? I mean, don't they contain the same numbers? I know the second is closed and the first is not, but I am talking in terms of numbers.

Comment: @IttayWeiss No they aren't.  If it's 0 then one contains the endpoints

Comment: @IttayWeiss : Not quite, one contains endpoints and the other doesn't

Comment: Look at any number between $0$ and $0+\epsilon$. Does the first one contain this number? Does the second?

Comment: Maybe you really mean $[0+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$? Still not the same, but at least you would have $$(0,1)=\bigcup_{0<\epsilon << 1}[0+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$$.

Comment: @MPW Also $$(0,1)=\bigcup_{0<\epsilon < 1}(0+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$$.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz : Yes, but I was trying to address the question. The open interval isn't *equal* to any of the closed intervals, but it can be *approximated* by them in this sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An important thing to keep in mind is that $\epsilon$ is a number just like any other. It just so happens that it's frequently used in a context where you are considering a sequence of *different* $\epsilon$ tending toward $0$. Let me give a couple examples.

If you write only $[0 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]$ for *fixed* $\epsilon > 0$, then this is a proper subset of $(0,1)$ because $\epsilon$ is a fixed constant. For example, if $\epsilon = 0.1$, then we're just talking about the interval $[0.1, 0.9]$.

What you presumably have in mind is something like
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} [0 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]
$$
or
$$
\bigcup_{0 < \epsilon < 0.5} [0 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon],
$$
which *is* equal to $(0,1)$ because $\epsilon$ is eventually smaller than any real number in $(0, 1)$. In either case, however, we are referring to the limit of a sequence of intervals using *different* $\epsilon$, not a single *fixed* $\epsilon$.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: This is what I was intuitively thinking I guess, but couldn't write down mathematically :) great!

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same.$$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\notin[0 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]$$But$$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\in(0 , 1)$$